# best way of connecting usb HID protocol and firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, usb, hid, browser-addons

I am working on a project where I would like to access data that's been stored on a device which is recognised as a usb HID class and I want to create a firefox plugin that access these data when needed.

1. what is the best way of aproaching this ?
   I know first of all I have to deal with the USB HID protocol and then I was thinking of making NPAPI cross browser plugin using QT-browser plugin.
2. Is there any better alternative. And please give a good solution for linking usb HID protocol and firefox  plugin as I am new to this.

thank you

Comment: Why going so low-level? what kind of usb device is this that you have to access on a level that is usually handled by device drivers?

Comment: Its a device in which there is smartcard storing info such as passwords and all

Comment: For anyone looking at this, Chrome provide chrome.usb and chrome.hid API to handle this, and Firefox started looking at integrating HIDAPI from signal11 see here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1198330